# Can’t read siteMetadata object from gatsby-config.js file with Gatsby and Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, gatsby

I am trying to read the content of siteMetadata object I defined in gatsby-config.js file, but each time I try I get this error

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
    at VariableDeclarator (/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries/index.js:277:81)
    at NodePath._call
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:118:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitMultiple
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:85:17)
    at TraversalContext.visit
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:144:19)
    at Function.traverse.node
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/index.js:94:17)
    at NodePath.visit
(/mnt/d/Repositories/FnStacks/HandyTrade/handytrade-store-web/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:95:18)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I am using Gatsby with typescript. I installed the plugin `gatsby-plugin-ts-loader` and the required setting on `gatsby-config.js`. I am trying to read the siteMetadata object in the starting page of my project. I tried by using `graphql` and `useStaticQuery` from `gatsby` library, but it failed. Here is how I proceeded

```js
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query IndexQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

And here is how I defined the SiteMetada object in  gatsby-config.js

```js
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Saturn web',
    author: 'FunctionalStack',
    description: 'Gatsby with typscript',
    siteUrl: 'http://localhost :8000/'
  }
```

The application is running without issues if I remove all the query reading siteMetadata. I am using gatsby on Windows Subsystem for Linux - Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: your error is not reproducable, I have no problems on my repo with typescript setup. There's a lot of variables however, if you could link to your repo or provide a minimal example that show the error, it'd be helpful!

Comment: Hi Derek, here is the repo that reproduce the error [https://github.com/dyesseyumba/gatsby-typescript-starter](https://github.com/dyesseyumba/gatsby-typescript-starter)

Comment: Thanks for adding the repo! in tsconfig, would you try to change `jsx` from `react` to `preserve`? gatsby use babel to statically remove graphql queries, so if ts remove jsx, it wouldn't be able to find queries. Let me know if that works

Comment: I changed `react` to `preserve` in `tsconfig.json` but it still generates the same error.

Comment: I cloned your repo & inspected further -- please see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run `tsc -p .` in your root directory and inspect the output, I find that tsc compiles this:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query IndexQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

into this:

```
var data = useStaticQuery(graphql(templateObject_1 || (templateObject_1 = tslib_1.__makeTemplateObject(["\n    query IndexQuery {\n      site {\n        siteMetadata {\n          title\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  "], ["\n    query IndexQuery {\n      site {\n        siteMetadata {\n          title\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  "]))));
```

Gatsby expects `graphql` queries to be in template literal, but tsc compiles them into regular functions.

In order to fix this, you'd need to change `tsconfig` to output at least `es6`.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  compileOptions: {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext", <-- or es6 & above
  }
}
```

---

Btw, I recently publish a ts plugin for gatsby that aims to make using gatsby in typescript as smooth as possible. One of the different thing it does is to automatically generate typings for graphql queries. I would appreciate it if you give it a try & let me know if there were any problems:

- [gatsby-plugin-ts](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-typescript/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-ts)
- [starter repo](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-starter-blog-ts)

Comment: Using your plugin, and your answer put an end to two hours of my tearing my hair off in frustration... Thanks!

Comment: @HappyKoala I'm glad to hear it helped, please don't hesitate to submit an issue if you run into any!